# Lopsided cross?

Tags: bug, design, logo

The cross that forms the `t` in Christianity seems a little lopsided.  msh210 posted an image [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9733968#9733968) that shows the blue on the right is much lighter than the blue on the left:

[image: 3D t.]

I suspect it's intended to give the cross a slightly 3D effect, but it looks more like something is not quite right.

Comment: Confound it all now you've ruined my everyday site usage until this gets fixed. It's not like I can just smooth it over with a user script, but it IS one of those things you can't un-see after its been pointed out.

Comment: @Caleb Well, you *could* provide your own version of the logo and use a user script to replace the site version with your own.